# ¿Cómo puedo recibir un parámetro de tipo dictionary en Java?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, parametros

Estoy consumiendo un servicio web(C#, .Net) para una app móvil en Android donde obtengo una lista y dentro de los parámetro de la lista me manda uno de tipo dictionary<String, String>, investigue un poco y vi que en Java lo podría recibir de tipo HashMap<String, String> o como Hashtable<String, String> pero cuando lo hago de esa forma no me hace la conexión al servicio. ¿Cómo puedo recibir ese tipo de dato en Java? o ¿Cómo puedo convertir el tipo dictionary a una lista o array?

Parámetros del Servicio:

```
private Clients(string nameP, string lastNameP, int ageP)
{
    name = nameP;
    lastName = lastNameP;
    age = ageP;
    listClients = new Dictionary<string, string>();
}
```

Mi clase donde recibo los parámetros:

```
public class Clients {
    public String Name;
    public String LastName;
    public int Age;
    //public List<Hashtable<String, String>> ListClient;
    //public List<Map<String, String>> ListClient;

    public DetailBankAccount() {

    }

    public DetailBankAccount(String name, String lastName, int age) {
        this.Name = name;
        this.LastName = lastName;
        this.Age = age;
        //ListClient = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public String getName() { return Name; }

    public void setName(String name) { Name = name; }

    public String getLastName() { return LastName; }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) { LastName = lastName; }

    public int getAge() { return Age; }

    public void setAge(int age) { Age = age; }

    //public List<Hashtable<String, String>> getListClient() { return ListClient; }

    //public void setListClient(List<Hashtable<String, String>> listClient) { ListClient = listClient; }

    //public List<Map<String, String>> getListClient() { return ListClient; }

    //public void setListClient(List<Map<String, String>> listClient) { ListClient = listClient; }
}
```

Comment: Dependerá enteramente de la response: ¿en qué formato estás recibiendo la información? ¿JSON, XML? Existen varios *deserializadores* que te generan la estructura de objetos automáticamente, como por ejemplo Jackson

Comment: En formato JSON amigo, para la deserialización estoy utilizando la biblioteca GSON con retrofit

Comment: Te recomiendo usar interfaces en lugar de clases concretas: Map en lugar de Dictionary, Hashtable o HashMap, del mismo modo que estás usando List en lugar de ArrayList. Sin ver exactamente el error es complicado poder ayudarte. ¿Podrías poner los logs para ver qué falla y el código del cliente HTTP?